# I can not publish an amendment to an application jsf

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

i've a problem with aplication developed in JSF, i fix the problem in development enviroment using netbeans, and everthing is OK.

The problem is when i try to publish the .class file, where the problem was, in apache tomcat 5.5.9 with de JVM 1.5.0_08, this file does work anymore.i dont know the validations that are done by tomcat, but i just change the name of the file that was being used for ".old".c ompilation was done on the same version of java tomcat

anyone know how to make this change??

Thank for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're redeploying an individual .class file in a web application?  I'm not surprised if that doesn't work; the class has probably already been loaded and JITted so replacing the bytecode on disk will have no effect.

Build a new version of the application's WAR (and the EAR that contains it, if there is one) and redeploy that.